# string Between two letters, two letters in a text to Delphi

Tags: delphi

insert a character ',' to string Between two letters, two letters in a text to Delphi

```
   function String2Hex(const Buffer: AnsiString): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Buffer) * 2);
  BinToHex(PAnsiChar(Buffer), PChar(Result), Length(Buffer));
end;
```

sample :
ABCDEFGHIJKL
Out text :
AB,CD,EF,GH,IJ,KL

Comment: What does the code snippet have to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand he probably wants to insert a `,` between each hex pair after `BinToHex()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly straightforward. The following function returns a string with commas inserted in such a way that the characters are grouped with group size 2:

```pascal
function AddCommas(const S: string): string;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  if S.Length <= 2 then
    Exit(S);
  SetLength(Result, S.Length + (S.Length - 1) div 2);
  j := 1;
  for i := 1 to S.Length do
  begin
    Result[j] := S[i];
    Inc(j);
    if not Odd(i) and (i < S.Length) then
    begin
      Result[j] := ',';
      Inc(j);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This function is rather efficient: notice that I avoid making unnecessary heap allocations.

To test it:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.Text := AddCommas(Edit1.Text);
end;
```

[image: Video of the function in action.]

---

But if you only want to use this to pretty-print binary data, it is better to use a combined function:

```pascal
function BytesToString(ABuf: PByte; ALen: Cardinal): string;
const
  HexDigits: array[0..$F] of Char = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if ALen = 0 then
    Exit('');
  SetLength(Result, 3 * ALen - 1);
  Result[1] := HexDigits[ABuf[0] shr 4];
  Result[2] := HexDigits[ABuf[0] and $0F];
  for i := 1 to ALen - 1 do
  begin
    Result[3*i + 0] := ',';
    Result[3*i + 1] := HexDigits[ABuf[i] shr 4];
    Result[3*i + 2] := HexDigits[ABuf[i] and $0F];
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to insert a `,` between each hex pair generated by `BinToHex()`, you can try something like this:

```pascal
function String2Hex(const Buffer: AnsiString): string;
var
  I, BufferLen: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  BufferLen := Length(Buffer);
  if BufferLen > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, BufferLen * 2);
    BinToHex(PAnsiChar(Buffer), PChar(Result), BufferLen);
    for I := 1 to BufferLen-1 do
      Insert(',', Result, I*3);
  end;
end;
```

Though, it would be more memory-efficient to use a `TStringBuider` instead, eg:

```pascal
function String2Hex(const Buffer: AnsiString): string;
const
  HexDigits: array[0..15] of Char = '0123456789abcdef';
var
  Bldr: TStringBuilder;
  Idx, BufferLen: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  BufferLen := Length(Buffer);
  if BufferLen > 0 then
  begin
    Bldr := TStringBuilder.Create((BufferLen * 2) + (BufferLen - 1));
    try
      Bldr.Append(HexDigits[Ord(Buffer[1]) shr 4]);
      Bldr.Append(HexDigits[Ord(Buffer[1]) and $0F]);
      for Idx := 2 to BufferLen do
      begin
        Bldr.Append(Char(','));
        Bldr.Append(HexDigits[Ord(Buffer[Idx]) shr 4]);
        Bldr.Append(HexDigits[Ord(Buffer[Idx]) and $0F]);
      end;
      Result := Bldr.ToString;
    finally
      Bldr.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```